# Applying multiplication across lists in haskell list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

haskell noob here. I'm doing [Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out) and came across this problem:

```
[ x*y | x <- [2,5,10], y <- [8,10,11]]
```

I rewrote it as follows

```
[ x*y | x <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], y <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] ]
```

the compiler barked at me probably because i was trying to multiple a list against another list. However if i wanted to recursively multiply each child list of `x` and `y` how could i do that?

This is the error i got:

```
No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of `*'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t0])
    In the expression: x * y
```

**UPDATE**

So far I've arrived here:

```
[ [a*b | a <- x, b <- y] | x <- [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], y <- [[4,5,6], [5,6,7]] ]
```

But this still returns a list of lists. What is an elegant way of flattening lists in Haskell?

Comment: What would your desired output be?

Comment: i want to multiply each element of each child list in x against each element of each child list in y. And then flatten into one array. does that make sense?

Comment: Hint: If you write a function `multList` using your first example, you could then replace `x*y` in your second.

Comment: How do i use `multList`? I'm a complete haskell noob.

Comment: He doesn't want you to use `multList`, he wants you to create one....  If you don't know what that means, I'd recommend grabbing any beginners Haskell tutorial.  The point is, mathematically speaking, there are many ways that you could define the multiplication of two vectors, so Haskell doesn't offer you a default.  It does, however, offer you a way to define it to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's try this out a couple ways. I'm going to use ghci to illustrate some examples:

```
% ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
λ [ x*y | x <- [2,5,10], y <- [8,10,11]]
[16,20,22,40,50,55,80,100,110]
λ -- so let's abstract that to a function
λ let multList xs ys = [ x*y | x <- xs, y <- ys ]
λ multList [2,5,10] [8,10,11]
[16,20,22,40,50,55,80,100,110]
λ -- let's try a simpler example
λ multList [1] [1]
[1]
λ -- now let's see if we can get your code working
λ -- (I tweaked the variable names, but that's just cosmetic)
λ [ xs*ys | xs <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], ys <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] ]

<interactive>:13:1:
    No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
λ -- yup, that's the error alright
λ -- let's skip multiplying. what else can we do with xs and ys?
λ -- well, we could create the pair (xs,ys)
λ [ (xs,ys) | xs <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], ys <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] ]
[([1,2,3],[4,5,6]),([1,2,3],[5,6,7]),([2,3,4],[4,5,6]),([2,3,4],[5,6,7])]
λ -- that's each pair of sublists, but we want to compute the products of each element
λ -- fortunately, that's exactly what multList does!
λ :t multList
multList :: Num t => [t] -> [t] -> [t]
λ [ multList xs ys | xs <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], ys <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] ]
[[4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18],[5,6,7,10,12,14,15,18,21],[8,10,12,12,15,18,16,20,24],[10,12,14,15,18,21,20,24,28]]
λ -- so that creates four sublists, one for each pair of lists.
λ -- what if we want to flatten that out?
λ -- well, we could just use `concat`
λ :t concat
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
λ concat [ multList xs ys | xs <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], ys <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] ]
[4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18,5,6,7,10,12,14,15,18,21,8,10,12,12,15,18,16,20,24,10,12,14,15,18,21,20,24,28]
λ -- alternately, we could try to inline our definition of `multList` and see where that gets us
λ [ [ x*y | x <- xs, y <- ys ] | xs <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], ys <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] ]
[[4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18],[5,6,7,10,12,14,15,18,21],[8,10,12,12,15,18,16,20,24],[10,12,14,15,18,21,20,24,28]]
λ -- nothing yet, but see how we've got two list comprehensions?
λ -- let's combine them into one!
λ [ x*y | xs <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], ys <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]], x <- xs, y <- ys ]
[4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18,5,6,7,10,12,14,15,18,21,8,10,12,12,15,18,16,20,24,10,12,14,15,18,21,20,24,28]
λ -- hey, that worked!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in GHCI:

```
Prelude> let combinate xs ys = [ x*y | x<-xs, y<-ys ]
Prelude> concat [ combinate x y | x <- [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]], y <- [[4,5,6],[5,6,7]] ]
[4,5,6,8,10,12,12,15,18,5,6,7,10,12,14,15,18,21,8,10,12,12,15,18,16,20,24,10,12,14,15,18,21,20,24,28]
```